# How to search branch revision number in Git

Tags: git, tortoisegit

We've just switched from SVN to Git and we've always used the revision count as our *File Version* in our build dll. Now that we've switched to Git, we are making the transition to just use hashes, but in the meantime we are using the commit count (`git rev-list --count HEAD`) from our release branch. Yes I know there are pitfalls with this.

However, I am trying to figure out how to map back to a specific commit in the branch when only having the commit number. I can search with either TortoiseGit or Bash with the hash but can't figure out how to do this with the branch name and revision count. How can I do that?

Comment: The Git commit hash is the preferred way to navigate to commits.  What is limiting you from using the Git hash in a normal way?

Comment: File Version is limited to 2 bytes for build number and expects numeric input. For various reasons it's not a simple transition to hashes. For the immediate future I need to use the revision count.

Comment: @tmwoods how about using tags if ambiguity can be avoided.

Comment: We're transitioning to tags, but still need to have an automated build number :(

Answer (score 1):

Go to TortoiseGit settings -> General -> Dialogs 1 and enable "Display branch revision number". After enabling the revision number is shown in each commit message in log dialog.

Comment: Yes I have this enabled now. But is there a way to search for this particular commit from the GUI (or Bash)? I realize I could scroll through them manually but am hoping to include this in an automated process later on.

Comment: I'm not aware of since these numbers are not unique. As these numbers are expensive to calculate, there also is no column in the log dialog for this.